# EF Core 3 Has Value Generator

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

in the modelBUilder for an entity, I am try to have the created and modified dates be set on add and updates by a custom generator.  The reason for going this path is because the DbContext that creates the models is being used a base class.  This base class is being inherited by SQL Server & SQLite EFCore extensions.  Because of this there should be database explicit functionality in the context.  The GetDateUTC() and triggers that were originally implemented SQL Server.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CommunicationSendRequest>(entity =>
            {
               ...

                entity.Property(p => p.CreatedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().HasValueGenerator<CreatedAtTimeGenerator>();
                entity.Property(p => p.ModifiedAt).ValueGeneratedOnUpdate().HasValueGenerator<ModifiedAtTimeGenerator>();

            });
```

but what is happening on add and updates both properties always set to new values.  Meaning on brand new inserts the modifiedat is set, and on updates the createdat date is set.  Which removes the true created at date.

[image: CreatedAt and Modifiedat dates]

The question is are those have value generators setup correctly?  Is there a way to accomplish this using the generators?  In the generators I tried to also check the state an return the value only if the state was added or modified.  But the state always equaled Detached.

```
 public class CreatedAtTimeGenerator : ValueGenerator<DateTimeOffset>
    {
        public override DateTimeOffset Next(EntityEntry entry)
        {
            if (entry == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entry));
            }

            return DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        }

        public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues { get; }
    }
    public class ModifiedAtTimeGenerator : ValueGenerator<DateTimeOffset>
    {
        public override DateTimeOffset Next(EntityEntry entry)
        {
            if (entry == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entry));
            }

            return DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        }

        public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues { get; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` after declaring the generator? (A shot in the dark, here)

Comment: @GuillermoPrandi i went away from this approach and set the created and modified dates in an override savechanges()

Comment: The `HasValueGenerator` is just a model-side value generator that fills value for your model's property when it has a default value (null for object, 0 for integer, ...) AND the property value is filled when the entity is added to the DbContext. So in your case, you always let all the date properties as default, each time added to the DbContext, they will be filled with your generator (ALWAYS). `ValueGeneratedOnXXX` works in a later phase (before saving the entity), so all the property values of non-default will be kept and saved. It may make sense only when there is no value generator.

Comment: involving the value generation, I think looks like the EFCore was designed in a confusing way. In this case the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` seems to be invalid and useless. If you want some value generated on adding as in this case, you must not use a value generator, maybe prepare some default value sql instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I actually did was to go away from the ValueGenerate concept all together and handle it the creation of CreatedAt, ModifiedAt, and added after this post was created DeletedAt dates by overriding the SaveChanges() methods.

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var selectedEntityList = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => (x.Entity is IEntityCreatedAt ||
                         x.Entity is IEntityModifiedAt ||
                         x.Entity is IEntityIsDeleted) &&
                        (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified)).ToList();

        selectedEntityList.ForEach(entity =>
        {
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                if (entity.Entity is IEntityCreatedAt)
                    ((IEntityCreatedAt)entity.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            }

            if (entity.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                if (entity.Entity is IEntityModifiedAt)
                    ((IEntityModifiedAt)entity.Entity).ModifiedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

                if (entity.Entity is IEntityIsDeleted)
                    if (((IEntityIsDeleted)entity.Entity).IsDeleted)
                        ((IEntityIsDeleted)entity.Entity).DeletedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            }
        });

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```